# Why can't I access my Intranet LDAPS with NADI?

Tags: plugins, security, authentication, customization

What would be a good plugin to access LDAPS (secure LDAP) over my company's Intranet?

I have tried [Next Active Directory Integration](https://active-directory-wp.com/) (NADI) which has been recommended by a site's vendor, which looks clean, has rather good documentation, and is free.

However, it is difficult for me at my level to buy the support package (it would take literally months!), and you cannot activate logs without a first verification of the LDAPS credentials - which I can't because I do not know how to set the connection parameters.

I am stumbling upon this error:

> `Verification Username does not match the required style. (e.g. "Administrator@test.ad")`

My questions are:

- Do anyone know how to activate logs without verifying the LDAPS connection (it says

  > `You have to verify the connection to the AD before saving.`
- What should I put in the fields **Base DN** and **username**?
- About **username**, What I have for username is something like that:

  ```
  cn=tech_user,ou=stdauth,ou=APPS,o=GROUP
  ```

How do I make it ok for NADI, where do I put the `@`?

- About **Base DN**, not sure what I should put ther, I have the LDAPS server name; do I have to translate it into something like that?

  ```
  dc=server,dc=company,dc=org
  ```

Any help appreciated.

Here is a screenshot if it can ring any bells:

> `Verification failed! Please check your logfile for further information`

Funny because I can't setup the logs...

[image: NADI LDAPS erros]

Additional information: I checked my LDAPS credentials using [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/), and it looked OK, with the following:

- Use LDAPS (SSL encryption)
- Provider : both (*Apache Dircetory LDAP Client API* & *JNDI*)
- **"Base DN or user"**

  ```
  cn=tech_user,ou=stdauth,ou=APPS,o=GROUP
  ```

[image: test with Apache Directory Studio]

Comment: I've had some success with Authorizer - https://wordpress.org/plugins/authorizer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom it may help... I found the answer:

> **Why?**

Because We were not actually using *Active Directory*, but some other kind of Directory provided by Oracle: OUD. It is possible to access it from another plugin, though:

> **How?**

We had to use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpdirauth/

- We succeeded configure the "*Use SSL*" case
- *Account Filter:* This is what your user ID is in the LDAP
- *Base DN:* in my case it was the last part of the BIND DN, `o=group`
- *BIND DN:* this is what I thought to be the **username**, including components until `o=group`
- *Account suffix:* didn't use
- *Authentication Groups:* didn't use

[image: wpDirAuth example with LDAPS]